# SQL Results: Employee Name and Location with Case Statement

Tags: sql, join, case-statement

In SQL...How can I match the building name from one table, with the employee id of another? When I run a query, like below, the building name is not displaying in the results.  It is leaving it blank, as stated in the Case statement of the script.  I don't think this should be happening.  I have attached an image of table examples and desired results.

[image: Example]

```
SELECT DISTINCT
emp.[emp_ln],
emp.[emp_fn],
empb.[emp_id],
'BUILDING_NAME' = CASE WHEN emp.[emp_id] = empb.[emp_id]                                             
                       THEN bld.[bld_name] ELSE ''
                                    END

FROM Employees as emp 
JOIN [dbo].[empbld] as empb on empb.[emp_id] = emp.[emp_id]
JOIN [dbo].[bl] as bld on bld.[bld_num] = empb.[bld_num]

Where emp.[emp_status] = ‘A’

Group by 
emp.[emp_ln],
emp.[emp_fn],
empb.[emp_id],
bld.[bld_name]
```

Comment: Your JOIN of `Employees` to `empbld` ensures that `emp.[emp_id]` is always equal to `empb.[emp_id]` so the CASE statement is not needed.  You also don't need the GROUP BY since you're not aggregating anything.

Comment: @squillman I think I left out some information.  I only need the building name if the employee number and the building number match.  Would I need the case statement, then?

Comment: That doesn't make sense.  Based on your sample data the employee number (emp_id?) and building number never match.  If you mean the emp_id columns then no, you don't need the CASE because the JOIN will only return rows where the emp_id values match.

Comment: @squillman I was trying to use an example query, but I now realize that does not exactly represent the one I am currently working on.  I'm going to try an figure it out on my own.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any aggregate function so you don't need to use `group by` clause.

From your expect result and table schema,I think you don't need use `case when`

Because `CASE WHEN` condition `emp.[emp_id] = empb.[emp_id]` will be always equal from the `join` statement

```
JOIN [dbo].[empbld] as empb on empb.[emp_id] = emp.[emp_id]
```

You can get `bld_name` from `bl` table directly.

```
SELECT 
  emp.[emp_ln],
  emp.[emp_fn],
  empb.[emp_id],
  bld.bld_name
FROM Employees as emp 
  JOIN [dbo].[empbld] as empb on empb.[emp_id] = emp.[emp_id]
  JOIN [dbo].[bl] as bld on bld.[bld_num] = empb.[bld_num]
Where emp.[emp_status] = ‘A’
```

*sqlfiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a3979/1*